# How to store Values of Different Data Types in R

Tags: r, vector, types, type-conversion

Here is my code:

```
a <- c(10,20,30)
b <- 40
```

How to store these two variables?

I have tried:

```
c <- c(a,b)
```

Vector c contains two elements, where first element is itself a vector and second is a single integer constant. 
But when I try to print like:

```
c[1] => It returns 10
c[2] => It returns 20
length(c) => It returns 4
```

But I want output as:

```
c[1] => should return vector a. i.e. 10,20,30
c[2] => should return 40
length(c) should return 2
```

How to do this? Or which data structure or data type should I use for "c" to store "a" and "b" to get the required results?

Comment: You want a `list`: `cc <- list(a,b)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `list`:

```
a <- c(10,20,30)
b <- 40
cc <- list(a,b)
cc
# [[1]]
# [1] 10 20 30

# [[2]]
# [1] 40

cc[[1]]
# [1] 10 20 30

cc[[2]]
# 40

length(cc)
# [1] 2
```